# commence < commensa = "joint table"?

Tags: etymology, word-comparison, english

M. J. Toswell, [*Today's Medieval University*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8654) p. 24 claims a new master

> would eat at the *commensa*, the joint table, after his commencement ceremony of stepping upward

Does the English word "commence" derive from a Latin word *commensa* < *con* + *mensa* (together at table)? [*Commensa*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=commensa) ∄ in Lewis & Short.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like folk etymology to me. I'm not aware of any word **commensa*, and the formation looks odd: prepositional prefixes aren't as common on nouns, and surely "together-table" would be expressed with an adjective? If anything I'd expect a verb **commensāre*, "sit at a table together".

The etymology I'm familiar with says "commence" comes from something like **com-initiāre* "begin together": compare Italian *cominciare*, Spanish *comenzar*.

Comment: There is a medieval Latin word *commensalis* (someone having meals with someone else), survived in the modern Italian word *commensale*. I would doubt it has anything to do with *commence* though.

Comment: @DenisNardin "commensal" even exists in English, though it's rare/technical.

Comment: And there is *commensalism* [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensalism): a long-term biological interaction (symbiosis) in which members of one species gain benefits while those of the other species neither benefit nor are harmed.

Comment: @hobbs Does that come from _mens_ (mind), _mensus_ (measurement), _mensa_ (table), or _mensis_ (month)‽

Comment: @Geremia mensa, I believe. It's the adjectival form of the "commensalism" that JobRozemond just mentioned.

Comment: @hobbs Yes, based upon what it means in English.